# typesetting a single mathematical symbol in a different font

Tags: fonts, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font)

Is there a command like `\mathfont[font]{}`, which enables me to use a different mathematical font for everything inside the parenthesis `{ }` ?

I want for example to use `\mathfont[txfonts]{$\mathbb{I}$}`, so that just the blackboard symbol for "I" is display using the `txfonts` font, while the rest of my text uses the usual computer modern latex font.

I know there are similar questions and answers, but I can't get anything out of them, since to apply them, I have to know slot in the font of the symbol I'd like to import.

Answer (score 1):

as it happens, the `amsfonts` blackboard bold was based on times, not on computer modern.  so, using `amsfonts` (which most people rightly associate with computer modern, and the symbols definitely *are* the cm style), `$\mathbb{I}$` will actually produce a times-styled letter.

it's not always the case, but when "variants" on the latin alphabet are involved (fraktur, script, etc.), the letters are usually positioned in the "normal" ascii locations, so it's worth trying that first (if you know what font you want/need) before creating a chart to check the actual position.

Answer (score 0):

See page 11 of [mathmode](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf). Normally the font package writer will provide relevant commands. For example with `amsfonts` you will have.

```
\[\mathfrak{T} t_2 \]

\[\mathbf{Z}\]

\[\mathbb{Z}\]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite understood your answer ( or the other one). How can the above display the $\mathbb{I}$ symbol from txfonts ? I actually use LyX and didn't inlcude any special package so I just assumed it was computer modern. The "[\mathbf{Z}\]
" command also won't work.

Comment: @user10324 You need to `\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}`. I am sure LyX has a way to include  packages?

Comment: Yes, it has those and I included them. But using your code still gives an error (I think a "\" was missing at the beginning of the second line). But even in that case \ [\mathbf{I}\] doesn't give me the symbol I would get if I were to use $\mathbb{I}$ in a document where in the preamble I have \usepackage{txfonts}.

Comment: @user10324 Yes I missed the backslash, try using `\[\mathbb{}\]`.

Comment: No, '\[\mathbb{I}\]' with then amsmath,amsfonts package isn't looking like it is when using the txfonts package.